# Is there a way inside the kernel of killing a kernel kthread just like `kill -9`?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Basically I have created a kernel thread using `kthread_create()`. The kthread does something repeatedly.

```
while() {
    //do something
    msleep_interruptible(1000);
}
```

Meanwhile, I want to kill this kthread when a certain condition is reached (e.g. a particular syscall is called, or a particular user-space process is terminated). I have read through the [kthread.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/kthread.c), but only found `kthread_stop()`, which is not like `kill -9`. What it does is just to set the `KTHREAD_SHOULD_STOP` bit in the `kthread->flag` and inside the kthread function body one has to call `kthread_should_stop()` to inquiry that bit and invoke `do_exit()` on its own.

I have tried this method like the following. The problem is that when the `kthread_stop()` is called, the kthread is usually in sleep (i.e. `msleep_interruptible(1000)`). Therefore, I always observe a delay between calling `kthread_stop()` and the kthread really exits. And this has led to an intolerable latency in my project. What I want is just like `kill -9`, that is, the kthread will terminate immediately after I call `kthread_stop()`. And ideas to realize that?

```
while(!kthread_should_stop()) {
    //do something
    msleep_interruptible(1000);
}
```

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer rather than including it in the question. (It's perfectly acceptable, even encouraged, to post and even accept an answer to your own question.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks for your suggestion. I have removed my solution from the question and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. It is not because of the sleep (i.e. `msleep_interruptible(1000)`). Actually this function does allow interruption and `kthread_stop()` also performs `wake_up_process()` to wake up the target kthread after setting the  `KTHREAD_SHOULD_STOP`. So ideally there shouldn't be any problem, meaning that regardless of the parameter of `msleep_interruptible()`, whenever `kthread_stop()` is invoked, the kthread should be waken up and terminated very soon.

However, there is a "lost wake-up" race condition (I got inspired by [this post](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/8144/print), which shows a very similar problem as mine). The tricky stuff is that the `msleep_interruptible()` is essentially containing two methods, `set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);` and `schedule_timeout();`, and that the `kthread_stop()` could be executed right before the two methods. So the order will like this:

```
[kthread]: //do something
[my syscall]: wake_up_process(kthread); //inside kthread_stop()
[kthread]: set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
[kthread]: schedule_timeout();
```

Thus, the `wake_up_process()` will simply be ignored by the kthread. To resolve this problem, one has to decouple `set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);` and `schedule_timeout();`. The following code works fine so far.

```
while(!kthread_should_stop()) {
    //do something
    set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
    if (kthread_should_stop()) {
        break;
    }
    schedule_timeout();
}
```

In this sense, there does exit a way inside the kernel to kill a kthread just like `kill -9`.